# Show network connections of a process

Tags: networking, process, monitoring

Is there a way to show the connections of a process? Something like that:

```
show PID
```

in which `show` is a command to do this, and `PID` is the ID of the process.
The output that I want is composed of all the connections of the process (in real-time). For example, if the process tries to connect to *173.194.112.151* the output is `173.194.112.151`.

A more specific example with Firefox:

```
show `pidof firefox`
```

and with Firefox I go at first to *google.com*, then to *unix.stackexchange.com* and finally to *192.30.252.129*. The output, when I close the browser, must be:

```
google.com
stackexchange.com
192.30.252.129
```

(Obviously with the browser this output is not realistic, because there are a lot of other related connections, but this is only an example.)

Comment: Under which Unix variant? Most have tools to do this, but different ones.

Comment: So essentially you want a log of all the connections ?

Comment: I think tcpdump or Wireshark should do the job then.

Comment: Some possible ways to do this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11709/how-can-i-capture-network-traffic-of-a-single-process

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You're looking for `strace`!
I found [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/12465/332836), but it's valid for Unix:

> To start and monitor an new process:
>
> ```
> strace -f -e trace=network -s 10000 PROCESS ARGUMENTS
> ```
>
> To monitor an existing process with a known PID:
>
> ```
> strace -p $PID -f -e trace=network -s 10000
> ```

Otherwise, but that's specific to Linux, you can [run the process in an isolated network namespace and use wireshark to monitor the traffic](https://askubuntu.com/a/499850/332836). This will probably be more convenient than reading the `strace` log:

> - create a test network namespace:
>
>   ```
>   ip netns add test
>   ```
> - create a pair of virtual network interfaces (veth-a and veth-b):
>
>   ```
>   ip link add veth-a type veth peer name veth-b
>   ```
> - change the active namespace of the veth-a interface:
>
>   ```
>   ip link set veth-a netns test
>   ```
> - configure the IP addresses of the virtual interfaces:
>
>   ```
>   ip netns exec test ifconfig veth-a up 192.168.163.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
>   ifconfig veth-b up 192.168.163.254 netmask 255.255.255.0
>   ```
> - configure the routing in the test namespace:
>
>   ```
>   ip netns exec test route add default gw 192.168.163.254 dev veth-a
>   ```
> - activate ip_forward and establish a NAT rule to forward the traffic coming in from the namespace you created (you have to adjust the network interface and SNAT ip address):
>
>   ```
>   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
>   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.163.0/24 -o YOURNETWORKINTERFACE -j SNAT --to-source YOURIPADDRESS
>   ```
>
>   (You can also use the MASQUERADE rule if you prefer)
> - finally, you can run the process you want to analyze in the new namespace, and wireshark too:
>
>   ```
>   ip netns exec test thebinarytotest
>   ip netns exec test wireshark
>   ```
>
>   You'll have to monitor the veth-a interface.

Comment: `strace` is actually specific to the Linux kernel, so it’s not valid for all Unix-like operating systems. As I understand it, BSD-like systems have similar utilities (DTrace and truss). Anyhow, good answer (so upvoted). Welcome to Stack Exchange.

Comment: The answer seems to point into the right direction, however I'm having problems interpreting [the `strace` output](https://www.pastiebin.com/5d1efde99a1ac) while examining `git fetch`. I was expecting to see some sort of URL included in the output, as also requested by the OP. Can someone help?

Answer (score 34):

Try

```
lsof -i -a -p $(pidof firefox | sed 's/ /,/g')
```

From [pidof man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof):

> Description
> Pidof finds the process id's (pids) of the named programs.
> It prints those id's on the standard output.

From [lsof man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof):

> - `-i` This option selects the listing of files any of whose Internet address matches the address specified in i. If no address is specified, this option selects the listing of all Internet and x.25 (HP-UX) network files.
> - `-a` AND
> - `-p` This option excludes or selects the listing of files for the processes whose optional *P*rocess *ID*entification (PID) numbers are in the comma-separated set s - e.g., `123` or `123,^456`. (There should be no spaces in the set.)

Why `sed` : When we have Multiple Processes matching the Process Name & we want that PID list from `pidof` to go to `lsof` which wants comma after each PID , we have to convert the spaces to commas. We can alternatively use `tr \ \,` too.
When we know we have Exactly Single Process with the given Process Name , we can skip `sed` & `tr`.

Comment: It partially works: it prints some of the current connections of the process, but then it closes automatically. For some programs the output is only this warning: `lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /home/user/.gvfs Output information may be incomplete.`

Comment: You may add options `-r1` to repeat output every second and `-w` to suppress warnings.

Comment: This only shows connections at a point in time, it doesn't list all the connections a process makes over its lifetime. Even if you put this command in a loop, it'll miss short-lived connections.

Comment: The questioner didn't ask to view the connections over it's lifetime. One could interpret `(in real-time)` as `from the point in time of tracking and forward`.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to add ` | sed 's/ /,/g'`, which is necessary.

Comment: @reinierpost I would have thought `tr \  ,` to be simpler.

Answer (score 14):

Here's another approach:

`ss -nap | grep $(pidof firefox)`

Sample output:

```
tcp    ESTAB      0      0          192.168.0.222:49050    216.58.218.164:443    users:(("firefox",3280,69))
tcp    ESTAB      0      0          192.168.0.222:48630    198.252.206.25:443    users:(("firefox",3280,106))
tcp    ESTAB      0      0          192.168.0.222:44220     216.58.217.38:443    users:(("firefox",3280,140))
tcp    ESTAB      0      0          192.168.0.222:52690    54.240.170.181:80     users:(("firefox",3280,107))
tcp    ESTAB      0      0          192.168.0.222:48744    198.252.206.25:443    users:(("firefox",3280,87))
tcp    ESTAB      0      0          192.168.0.222:48811    198.252.206.25:443    users:(("firefox",3280,73))
```

Comment: This only shows connections at a point in time, it doesn't list all the connections a process makes over its lifetime. Even if you put this command in a loop, it'll miss short-lived connections.

Answer (score 8):

You can try also with `netstat -p`. From the man page:

> netstat  - Print network connections, routing tables, interface statistics, masquerade connections, and multicast memberships

To show only networking connections use `netstat -tup`. Notice that to see the process PID you may need to be root.

If you don't have `netstat`on your system you may have `ss`, which has almost the exact syntax. You can use then `ss -tup` (as root).

Comment: This only shows connections at a point in time, it doesn't list all the connections a process makes over its lifetime. Even if you put this command in a loop, it'll miss short-lived connections.

Comment: netstat -p | grep firefox | grep tcp

Comment: @Gilles Which means it is a great answer for anyone wanting to see the connections at a point in time. As was my case recently.